# To get record of two dates

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want two dates if I post start date and end date from submit form. I have attendance record table. I want to retrieve this table. How can I do that?
This is my code. It redirects to test.php. How can I retrieve another page? Who can help me kindly?

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="test.php">    

    <!--Start Date-->  
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group required">
                   <label for="startdate" class="control-label">Start Date:</label>                                
                  <input class="form-control"  placeholder="Choose Date " type="text" id="datepicker-8" name="startdate" required="required" />                    
               </div>
        </div>  


        <!--End Date-->  
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group required">
                   <label for="enddate" class="control-label">End Date:</label>                               
                  <input class="form-control"  placeholder="Choose Date " type="text" id="datepicker-9" name="enddate" required="required" />

               </div>              
        </div>
         <!--Create Button-->     
    <div class=""> <br/>         
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Search" />          
    </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by retrieve another page while you are redirecting you form to `test.php`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first get both start date and end date in vairable using $_REQUEST like that way.

```
$start_data = $_REQUEST['startdate'];
$end_data = $_REQUEST['enddate'];
```

Now you need to use sql query to fetch data from table :

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from table_name where startdate='$start_data' AND enddate='$end_data'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  // Print your variable here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `test.php`:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

Then submit your form. You will see all the fields and values that were contained in the form. You can access individual fields like so: `$startdate = $_POST['startdate']`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you click the submit button the page will be redirected to test.php file, the content which you will write in test.php will be shown. Now to retrieve date from post u can use `$startdate=$_POST['startdate']` simillarly for `$enddate=$_POST['enddate']`. After this use queries to fetch the data from database using the startdate and enddate variable